# Parameterization in Selenium and TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am learning Selenium by my own. I am not sure about the right way to parameterize the test cases while using Selenium with TestNG Framework.
Is it better to pass the parameters in TestNG.XML file OR keep a seperate spreadsheet. For example, I need to parameterize LOGIN functionality with 100 different users' login details. Where to keep the username/password details of 100 users?

If Parametrization through a spreadsheet works best, then what exactly is the purpose of having a testng.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

For parameterization **Testng** provide you two methods.

> 1. By TestNG XML file.
> 2. By Using @DataProvider

**When to use TestNG XML file?**

When you want to define simple parameters for decision making you can use XML file.

*Example:* Simply passing browser value like ff, chrome from .xml file ie to decide the browser to be used for test case execution.

**When to use @DataProvider?**

Specially in Data driven testing i.e  when same test method needs to be  run multiple times with different data-sets you can use DataProvider and it is also used to handle  complex parameters or complex objects like reading  from a property file or a database, etc.

- In your case around 100 different users' login details needs to be passed so
  i would suggest put them in excel file and read them using APACHE POI
  / JXL reason why not to go for @DataProvider is logically its bad
  practice to pass 100 values in your DataProvider class which may also
  result in poor performance and increased the complexity of your test
  code.

Comment: Many thanks Rupesh. I went through some examples and I have another doubt, when using @-DataProvider and passing the values to Test I can see in examples that without a loop the @-Test is executing , say 6 times, if 6 values are passed via @-Dataprovider. How is this happening without a loop? Results showing 6 Tests are run. please provide some input. TIA @mk08 your input pls.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is preferred to keep your @Test methods without any parameters.But to answer, you can parametrize your tests as
   explained here [Parametrized tests in TestNG](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm)
2. If you are trying to pass 100 different login details, would advice you to keep it in separate spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a bit confused here, if parameterization via spreadsheet works best, then what is the actual purpose of having a testng.xml file? Can I build a complete project/framework without having a testng.xml file? TIA (new to Selenium).

Comment: Purpose of testng.xml is to have better control over your test case execution. You will find it helpful when there are suites to be run with n number of tests. You can have project run without having testng.xml but again it may require more work on your test code side. Rest I think as answered by Rupesh Shinde clears most of the things. :)

Comment: Many thanks. I went through some examples and I have another doubt, when using @-DataProvider and passing the values to Test I can see in examples that without a loop the @-Test is executing , say 6 times, if 6 values are passed via @-Dataprovider. How is this happening without a loop? Results showing 6 Tests are run. please provide some input. TIA

Comment: @-DataProvider sends the data to Test method as array of objects(Object[][]). Test method then gets executed (here)6 times, once with each row of object[][]. This is implicitly getting handled. As a test case writer, you need to make sure that the number of test parameters=2nd dimention of array returned by DataProvider.